# Create a student record using structures and pointers in C language

Tags: c

I am having issues with trying to build a student record. The `struct` has four variables which are `id`, `name`, `age`, and `GPA`. I am supposed to read in a file and dynamically allocate memory for a new student `struct` which is suppose to hold a data set (student record). Then finally I'm supposed to print the total number of students that were successfully created from the file, `average age` (as float or double), and `average GPA` (as float or double). As you can see I am very lost and would appreciate any help in coding this project. Will be forever grateful! Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[255];
    int age;
    float gpa;
}student;

int makeStudent(FILE *fpin, student *students)
{
    int num_Students = 0;
    int rowNum = 0;

    students = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student) * 50);

    if((fscanf(fpin, "%d", students->id) < 0))
    {
        printf("Cannot create student record from file row # %d: id is invalid", rowNum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((fscanf(fpin, "%s", students->name) != 1))
    {
        printf("Cannot create student record from file row # %d: name is invalid", rowNum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((fscanf(fpin, "%d", students->age) < 0))
    {
        printf("Cannot create student record from file row # %d: age is invalid", rowNum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf(fpin, "%d", students->gpa);
    if(students->gpa < 0.0 || students->gpa > 4.0)
    {
        printf("Cannot create student record from file row # %d: GPA is invalid", rowNum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    num_Students++;
    rowNum++;
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    FILE *fpin;
    char name[255];
    int size = 0;

    fpin = fopen("student.txt", "r");

    student studentRecord[255];
    while(fgets(name, 255, fpin) != NULL)
        printf("%s", name);

    /*while(1)
    if(!makeStudent(fpin, &studentRecord[size]))
    break;
    ++size;
    if(fpin == NULL)
    {
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    */

    fclose(fpin);
    return 0;
}
```

FILE DATA BELOW:

```
1
Bob Smith
24
3.5
2
Jill Williams
23
3.6
3
Tom Jones
32
2.4
4
Julie Jackson
21
3.1
5
Al Brown
23
3.35
6
Juan Garcia
22
3.4
-7
Melissa Davis
20
3.2
8
Jack Black
44
1.1
```

Comment: Thanks Zach for editing looks much better!

Comment: Carla, you will need to begin by defining a maximum number of students you are dealing with (unless you want to use a linked-list). `#define MAXS 200`. The you define your struct. In `main()` you will allocate 200 pointers to your struct with `calloc` not `malloc` so you explicitly set the pointers to `NULL`. Then as you read each set of data from the file, you can allocate a struct with `malloc` and fill in the data. since you are using pointers, use the arrow notation to access struct members (e.g. `student->name`) instead of the `.` operator. You can travers all structs while *ptr != NULL

Comment: Every time you call the function you are allocating space for 50 student with the line: `students = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student) * 50);` (losing the old ones **memory leak**), you should do this outside the functions, and pass the function (pointer to array (you have this already), last used index in the array, size of the array (for bound check)). In the function you increment the last index used, read the info and add the student.

Comment: Without seeing `struct student` we can't tell if this `fscanf(fpin, "%s", students->name)` is a timebomb or not...

Comment: @CarlaRamirez - do you have a datafile you are reading? If so, do you mind showing a few lines showing how the student records are kept?

Comment: I do have a data file

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin 1
Bob Smith
24
3.5
2
Jill Williams
23
3.6
3
Tom Jones
32
2.4
4
Julie Jackson
21
3.1
5
Al Brown
23
3.35
6
Juan Garcia
22
3.4
-7
Melissa Davis
20
3.2
8
Jack Black
44
1.1

Comment: each line has a single piece of information of the student. line 1 has student id, line 2 has student first and last name, line 3 has student age, and line 4 has students GPA

Comment: Note that you probably need to pass a `student **students` (a double pointer, rather than a single point) so that code outside this function can access the array of structures allocated inside the function.  As it stands, you modify the local variable `students`, but that doesn't change the value in the function that calls this one.

Comment: sorry for the format, first time using this site

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so using a double pointer in makeStudent function will allow me to access that array inside main method for example? how would the syntax look in C language to access that array built in makeStudent? I am assuming once I access it in main then I can print the desired info..

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example adapted to your problem. I have removed the validation checks so the logic is more clear. In the code where you see at `//(1)` or `//(2)` that corresponds to the validation check at the end of the file that can be replaced when you a comfortable with the logic. **Note:** that are many ways to read the data and many ways to allocate and keep track of your structure index. Here an arbitrary `200` max student count was chosen. For an unlimited amount, you can either implement a reallocation scheme or create a `linked-list` from your structure. That would complicate the example.

Here I have used a comma separate datafile with your setup. That can be easily changed. I have chosen to read the data file line-by-line with `getline()` instead of `fscanf`. You can do it either way, although, line-oriented input with `getline()` is generally much more flexible. The example data file is (put together before your edit):

```
$ cat dat/students.txt
2158,John Q. Student,11,88.42
2159,Jane Q. Student,12,89.31
2160,Jill Q. Student,13,90.83
2161,Jack Q. Student,13,82.1
2162,Jene Q. Student,10,89.18
```

The code below is fairly basic, but it does employ one trick to allow iteration over all students without having to maintain or pass a count to any function used. The code allocates `200` pointers to struct using `calloc` instead of `malloc` and then later allocates space for each struct as lines are read. Allocating with `calloc` sets all pointers to an explicit `NULL` allowing you to iterate over the pointers that have been assigned and stopping when your reach the first pointer that is `NULL`. (you will see this before all students are printed at the end). Go through the code, build it, run it, and come back with questions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* maximum number students */
#define MAXS 200

typedef struct student {
    int id;
    char *name;
    int age;
    float gpa;
} student;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf ("filename.csv please...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *line = NULL;          /* pointer to use with getline ()   */
    ssize_t read = 0;           /* characters read by getline ()    */
    size_t n = 0;               /* number of bytes to allocate      */
    char *p = NULL;             /* pointer to use parsing line      */
    char *sp = NULL;            /* 2nd pointer to use parsing line  */
    student **students = NULL;  /* ptr to array of stuct student    */
    int cnt = 0;                /* counter for number allocated     */
    int field = 0;              /* couter for field in line         */
    int it = 0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");  /* open file , read only            */
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n");
        return 1;
    }

    students = calloc (MAXS, sizeof (*students)); /* allocate 200 ptrs set to NULL */
    // (1)
    while ((read = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {    /* read each line in input file */

        sp = p = line;      /* set start ptr and ptr to beginning of line */
        field = 0;          /* set/reset field to 0 */

        // (2)
        students[cnt] = malloc (sizeof (**students));   /* alloc a stuct with malloc    */
        // (3)
                            /* parse id, name, age, gpa     */
        while (*p)          /* for each character in line   */
        {
            if (*p == ',')  /* if ',' end of field found    */
            {
                *p = 0;     /* set as null-term char (temp) */

                if (field == 0) students[cnt]->id   = atoi (sp);
                if (field == 1) students[cnt]->name = strdup (sp); /* strdup allocates for you */
                if (field == 2) students[cnt]->age  = atoi (sp);

                *p = ',';   /* replace with original ','    */
                sp = p + 1; /* set new start ptr start pos  */
                field++;    /* update field count           */
            }
            p++;            /* increment pointer p          */
        }
        students[cnt]->gpa = strtof (sp, NULL);   /* read gpa (sp already set to begin) */

        cnt++;              /* increment students count     */
    }

    /* iterate over all students and print */
    printf ("\nThe students in the class are:\n\n");
    while (students[it])
    {
        printf ("  %d   %s   %d   %6.2f\n",
                students[it]->id, students[it]->name, students[it]->age, students[it]->gpa);
        it++;
    }

    int total = it;
    printf ("\nTotal number of students: %d\n", total);

    /* compute average age and gpa*/
    float avg_age = 0;
    float avg_gpa = 0;

    for (it = 0; it < total; it++)
    {
        avg_age += (float)students[it]->age;
        avg_gpa += students[it]->gpa;
    }
    avg_age /= (float)total;
    avg_gpa /= (float)total;

    printf ("Average Age of students : %.2f\n", avg_age);
    printf ("Average GPA of students : %.2f\n\n", avg_gpa);

    // free memory

    return 0;
}
```

**build:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o student structstudent.c
```

**Note:** always compile with at least `-Wall -Wextra` warning enabled to help point out problems in your code.

**output:**

```
./student students.txt

The students in the class are:

  2158   John Q. Student   11    88.42
  2159   Jane Q. Student   12    89.31
  2160   Jill Q. Student   13    90.83
  2161   Jack Q. Student   13    82.10
  2162   Jene Q. Student   10    89.18

Total number of students: 5
Average Age of students : 11.80
Average GPA of students : 87.97
```

**validations removed:**

```
// Validation checks:
// (1)
//     if (!students) {
//         fprintf (stderr, "calloc failed to allocate students\n");
//         return 1;
//     }
// (2)
//         if (cnt == MAXS) {  /* test cnt less than MAXS */
//             fprintf (stderr, "Error: MAXS reached\n");
//             break;
//             /* you will realloc students here in real life */
//         }
// (3)
//         if (!students[cnt]) {
//             fprintf (stderr, "malloc failed to allocate students\n");
//             return 1;
//         }
```

---

**Edit to read given format:**

You can replace the code above that reads a `csv` file in order to read the data file in the format you have given. Just replace everything from the common start and common end lines in its entirety. In addition add `int linecnt = 0;` in the variable declaration section:

```
while ((read = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {    /* read each line in input file */

    if ((linecnt % 4) == 0)                             /* after every 4th read         */
        students[cnt] = malloc (sizeof (**students));   /* alloc a stuct with malloc    */

    switch (linecnt)                /* parse id, name, age, gpa     */
    {
        case 0 :    students[cnt]->id   = atoi (line);
                    linecnt++;      /* increment linecnt        */
                    break;
        case 1 :    line[read -1] = 0;  /* strip newline char   */
                    students[cnt]->name = strdup (line);
                    linecnt++;
                    break;
        case 2 :    students[cnt]->age  = atoi (line);
                    linecnt++;
                    break;
        case 3 :    students[cnt]->gpa  = strtof (line, NULL);
                    linecnt = 0;    /* reset linecnt to 0       */
                    cnt++;          /* increment students count */
                    break;
    }
}

/* iterate over all students and print */
printf ("\nThe students in the class are:\n\n");
while (students[it])
{
    printf ("  %3d   %16s   %d   %6.2f\n",
            students[it]->id, students[it]->name, students[it]->age, students[it]->gpa);
    it++;
}
```

**Build, Run and New Output:**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o students2 students2.c

$ ./students2 students_2.txt

The students in the class are:

    1          Bob Smith   24     3.50
    2      Jill Williams   23     3.60
    3          Tom Jones   32     2.40
    4      Julie Jackson   21     3.10
    5           Al Brown   23     3.35
    6        Juan Garcia   22     3.40
   -7      Melissa Davis   20     3.20
    8         Jack Black   44     1.10

Total number of students: 8
Average Age of students : 26.12
Average GPA of students : 2.96
```

Comment: what is the reason for the" if(argc < 2) printf("filename.csv please");" When I run the code it only prints this message not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: That just means if you don't give the program a file name as an argument on the command line, it won't run and exits telling you to give it a "filename please" - the csv is just a reminder that it wants a comma separated values file. It's just a way of checking that the program has been given the required input. You could make the program ask for a filename, but that just makes the code longer. Easiest just to pass what you need on the command-line. So run it with `./programname input_filename`. See the **output:** section for an example.

Comment: @CarlaRamirez There are many good **core C** principals involved in this project you are doing. Take the time to understand what each line of code does **AND** why it does it. Your project is exceptionally good at forcing you to think **"How am I going to tie all these structs together in a useable way?"** That applies to collections of any type of data structure. The dynamic allocation and pointer use is another good learning opportunity. Don't shortcut the analysis (even though it is tempting). Ask again, when you get stuck.

Comment: @CarlaRamirez: I have added a new section to the bottom of the answer that will read the data in the format you provided. Take a look. As others and I have said, when you declare students with as `student *students` instead of `student **students`, you make it nearly impossible to **tie the stucts together** in a way that will let you pass all students to a function or iterate over all students in your program. You can do it your way, but you will need to keep **global variables** for `count` and the sums of the `age` and `gpa` in order to calculate the average at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777772/im-trying-to-create-a-student-record-using-structures-and-pointers-in-c-language#comment40315959_25777772), I said:

> Note that you probably need to pass a `student **students` (a double pointer, rather than a single pointer) so that code outside this function can access the array of structures allocated inside the function. As it stands, you modify the local variable `students`, but that doesn't change the value in the function that calls this one.

And [Carla Ramirez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4029030/carla-ramirez) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777772/im-trying-to-create-a-student-record-using-structures-and-pointers-in-c-language#comment40316266_25777772):

> so using a double pointer in `makeStudent` function will allow me to access that array inside `main` method for example? How would the syntax look in C language to access that array in `makeStudent`?

The simplest way is to rename the parameter (I chose `p_students`) and make a local variable `student *students` in place of the parameter.  Then write the code as:

```
int makeStudent(FILE *fpin, student **p_students)
{
    int num_Students = 0;
    int rowNum = 0;

    student *students = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student) * 50);
    if (students == 0)
        return 0;
    *p_students = students;
```

and the rest of the code can use `students` just as before.

If you can't or won't do that, then:

```
int makeStudent(FILE *fpin, student **students)
{
    int num_Students = 0;
    int rowNum = 0;

    *students = (student *)malloc(sizeof(student) * 50);
    if (*students == 0)
        return 0;
```

and in the rest of the code, reference `*student` (or, more frequently, `(*student)`) where you previously had just `student`.  However, that's make a notational rod for your own back; it is silly to make the code harder to understand than it needs to be.

Note, though, that the `makeStudent()` code would need to loop through up to 50 students.

In the `main()` program, you'd write:

```
student *students = 0;
int n_students = makeStudent(fpin, &students);

if (n_students > 0)
{
    …print them…
    free(students);  // Free them (let them go home at the end of the day/term/year?)
}
```

#### Alternatively

Since your function is written to process one student, you could do the memory allocation in the `main()` program and not try any memory allocation in `makeStudent()`.  Then `main()` might look like:

```
student students[50];

for (i = 0; makeStudent(fpin, &students[i]) != 0; i++)
{
    …process a student…
}
```

And the code in `makeStudent()` might be just:

```
int makeStudent(FILE *fpin, student *students)
{
    if ((fscanf(fpin, "%d", students->id) < 0))
    {
        printf("Cannot create student record from file row # %d: id is invalid", rowNum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    …etcetera…
```

…except that the `rowNum` would need to be passed in (it is `i` in my revised `main()`)…