# how to free memory in c in this context

Tags: c, valgrind

context:  [Create a student record using structures and pointers in C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777772/create-a-student-record-using-structures-and-pointers-in-c-language#comment40315959_25777772)

```
#define MAXS    200
typedef struct student{
    int id;
    char *name;
    int age;
    float gpa;
}student;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: filename csv. please\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *line = NULL;   /* pointer to use with getline ()   */
    ssize_t read = 0;    /* characters read by getline ()    */
    size_t n = 0;        /* number of bytes to allocate      */
    char *p = NULL;      /* pointer to use parsing line      */
    char *sp = NULL;      /* 2nd pointer to use parsing line      */
    int field = 0;
    int cnt = 0;         /* counter for number allocated     */
    student **students = NULL;  /* ptr to array of stuct student    */
    int it = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to open file for reading\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    students = calloc(MAXS, sizeof(*students));
    if(!students){
        fprintf(stderr,"calloc failed to allocate\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // 2158,John Q. Student,11,88.42
    while((read = getline(&line,&n,fp)) != -1){
        sp = p = line;
        field = 0;

        students[cnt] = malloc(sizeof(**students));
        if(!students[cnt]){
            fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed to allocate students\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while(*p){
            if(*p == ',')
            {
                *p = 0;
                if(field == 0) students[cnt]->id  = atoi(sp);
                if(field == 1) students[cnt]->name  = strdup(sp);
                if(field == 2) students[cnt]->age = atoi(sp);

                *p = ',';
                sp = p+1;
                field++;
            }
            p++;
        }
        students[cnt]->gpa = strtof(sp,NULL);
        cnt ++;
        if(cnt == MAXS){
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: MAXS reached\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("cnt = %d\n",cnt);
    /* iterate over all students and print */
    printf("\nThe students in the class are: \n\n");
    while(students[it]){
        printf(" %d %s %d %6.2f\n"
            ,students[it]->id,students[it]->name,students[it]->age,students[it]->gpa);
        it++;
    }

    int total = it;
    printf("\nTotal number of students: %d\n",total);

    /* compute average age and gpa*/
    float avg_age = 0;
    float avg_gpa = 0;

    for(it = 0; it < total; it++)
    {
        avg_age += (float) students[it]->age;
        avg_gpa += (float) students[it]->gpa;
    }
    avg_age /= (float) total;
    avg_gpa /= (float) total;

    printf("Average Age of students: %.2f\n",avg_age);
    printf("Average GPA of students: %.2f\n",avg_gpa);

    for(it = 0; it < MAXS; it++){
        free(students[it]);
    }
    free(students);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

valgrind command output:

```
==567070==
==567070== HEAP SUMMARY:
==567070==     in use at exit: 672 bytes in 7 blocks
==567070==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 8 frees, 7,512 bytes allocated
==567070==
==567070== 80 bytes in 5 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==567070==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==567070==    by 0x491560E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==567070==    by 0x1094B4: main (in /home/jian/helloc/a.out)
==567070==
==567070== 120 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==567070==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==567070==    by 0x48ED1A2: getdelim (iogetdelim.c:62)
==567070==    by 0x109261: main (in /home/jian/helloc/a.out)
==567070==
==567070== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 3
==567070==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==567070==    by 0x48EC6CD: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==567070==    by 0x48EC6CD: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==567070==    by 0x10920C: main (in /home/jian/helloc/a.out)
==567070==
==567070== LEAK SUMMARY:
==567070==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 5 blocks
==567070==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==567070==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==567070==    still reachable: 592 bytes in 2 blocks
==567070==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==567070==
==567070== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

If i PUT `free(students[it]->name);` In the last for loop, then it will `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` . How can I free all the memory in this context?

Comment: Missing headers, MAXS

Comment: `fclose` will fix one of the issues.

Comment: `free(line)` should release the memory allocated by `getdelim`

Comment: If a line doesn't have sufficient fields, you never set the value of `students[it]->name`. Consequently, you call `free` with an uninitialized value. Try to add `students[cnt]->name = NULL;` just before `while(*p){`. It's always valid to call  `free` with NULL

Comment: As @SupportUkraine wrote, or use `calloc()` to get space for the student details... At least then you know what the bytes look like before dealing with... (ugh) _in-put_...

Comment: oh... `for(it = 0; it < MAXS; it++){` --> `for(it = 0; it < cnt; it++){`

Comment: When you iterate to MAX **and** you have read in **less** than MAX students then `free(students[it]->name);` will dereference a NULL pointer as soon as it reach the value of `cnt`. That's a seg fault....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Changed `MAXS` to `cnt` in the loop where you free students, and added a free of the `name`.

```
    for(it = 0; it < cnt; it++){
        free(students[it]->name);
        free(students[it]);
    }
```

2. `getline()` allocates line, so free that in loop and each exit point.
3. Initialized name in case the field is missing (@SupportUkraine).
4. fclose(fp) after the loop that reads the file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAXS 100

typedef struct student{
    int id;
    char *name;
    int age;
    float gpa;
}student;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: filename csv. please\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char *line = NULL;   /* pointer to use with getline ()   */
    ssize_t read = 0;    /* characters read by getline ()    */
    size_t n = 0;        /* number of bytes to allocate      */
    char *p = NULL;      /* pointer to use parsing line      */
    char *sp = NULL;      /* 2nd pointer to use parsing line      */
    int field = 0;
    int cnt = 0;         /* counter for number allocated     */
    student **students = NULL;  /* ptr to array of stuct student    */
    int it = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(!fp){
        fprintf(stderr,"failed to open file for reading\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    students = calloc(MAXS, sizeof(*students));
    if(!students){
        fprintf(stderr,"calloc failed to allocate\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // 2158,John Q. Student,11,88.42
    while((read = getline(&line,&n,fp)) != -1){
        sp = p = line;
        field = 0;

        students[cnt] = malloc(sizeof(**students));
        if(!students[cnt]){
            fprintf(stderr,"malloc failed to allocate students\n");
            free(line);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        students[cnt]->name = NULL;
        while(*p){
            if(*p == ',')
            {
                *p = 0;
                if(field == 0) students[cnt]->id  = atoi(sp);
                if(field == 1) students[cnt]->name = strdup(sp);
                if(field == 2) students[cnt]->age = atoi(sp);

                *p = ',';
                sp = p+1;
                field++;
            }
            p++;
        }
        students[cnt]->gpa = strtof(sp,NULL);
        cnt ++;
        if(cnt == MAXS){
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: MAXS reached\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(line);

    printf("cnt = %d\n",cnt);
    /* iterate over all students and print */
    printf("\nThe students in the class are: \n\n");
    while(students[it]){
        printf(" %d %s %d %6.2f\n"
            ,students[it]->id,students[it]->name,students[it]->age,students[it]->gpa);
        it++;
    }

    int total = it;
    printf("\nTotal number of students: %d\n",total);

    /* compute average age and gpa*/
    float avg_age = 0;
    float avg_gpa = 0;

    for(it = 0; it < total; it++)
    {
        avg_age += (float) students[it]->age;
        avg_gpa += (float) students[it]->gpa;
    }
    avg_age /= (float) total;
    avg_gpa /= (float) total;

    printf("Average Age of students: %.2f\n",avg_age);
    printf("Average GPA of students: %.2f\n",avg_gpa);

    for(it = 0; it < cnt; it++){
        free(students[it]->name);
        free(students[it]);
    }
    free(students);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

and valgrind hates us less:

```
==1387007== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1387007==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1387007==   total heap usage: 21 allocs, 28 frees, 6,798 bytes allocated
==1387007==                                                                                                            
==1387007== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: I think this was exactly what OP did. And got a seg fault. See last lines of question and my comment

Comment: MAXS 100 and students 8.  UB, probably, I will update answer in a second with your suggestion.

Comment: @AllanWind It will work **if** a value was assigned to `students[it]->name`. However, depending on input, that's not always the case

Comment: `for(it = 0; it < cnt; it++){`  -- this code looks vaguely familiar `:)` There are `MAXS` pointers declared which are freed with `free (students)` outside the loop.

Comment: It ought to blow up but doesn't (for it >= cnt).  Hmm.  Nice, missed the segfault in the wall of text from valgrind.  Ha!

Comment: So long as both pointers are `NULL` it won't blow up -- that's just a no op. (and since `calloc()` was used ...)  Both AREN''T NULL the 2nd derefence gets you.

Comment: students[it] is null so it's a null dereference.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin hmmm ... if both pointers are NULL, `students[it]->name` will blow up

Comment: All `student` pointers `0` to `MAXS` are initialized `NULL`. So from `cnt` to `MAXS` `student[i]` is `NULL`, but `student[i]->BOOM` for those after `cnt`.

Comment: @SupportUkraine - good eyes.

Comment: Let me know if missing anything or require clarification.

Comment: @user3386109 Will do.  I never use getline() it's deprecated it seems.

Comment: I knew this had to be my fault: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26695732/3422102

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin For someone in your profession I thought you would be familiar with the 3 little sentences that will get you through life. "#1: Cover for me. #2: Oh, good idea, boss. #3: It was like that when I got here.” :-)